# Is it possible to give arguments inside variables in robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

```
Library  REST  ${base_url} 

*** Keywords ***
Get Requests
  GET  ${rest_of_the_url}
  Output  response body

*** Test Cases ***
Do some searching
  Get Requests

*** Variables ***
${base_url} https://business.com
${rest_of_the_url} /api/${department}/${person_name}
```

How can I assign values to ${department} and ${person_name}? I don't want to set those inside ***Variables*** because then I cannot write multiple scenarios inside one .robot file. Is it possible to do the assignment as arguments?

Answer (score 1):

i do not think there is a way to pass arguments within the variables,

The below section is straight from the documentation of Robotframework,
where you can create Variables inside variables

**Variables inside variables**
Variables are allowed also inside variables, and when this syntax is used, variables are resolved from the inside out. For example, if you have a variable ${var${x}}, then ${x} is resolved first. If it has the value name, the final value is then the value of the variable ${varname}. There can be several nested variables, but resolving the outermost fails, if any of them does not exist.

In the example below, Do X gets the value ${JOHN HOME} or ${JANE HOME}, depending on if Get Name returns john or jane. If it returns something else, resolving ${${name} HOME} fails.

```
*** Variables ***
${JOHN HOME}    /home/john
${JANE HOME}    /home/jane

*** Test Cases ***
Example
    ${name} =    Get Name
    Do X    ${${name} HOME}
```

Comment: Thanks! I somehow missed this, need to think if this is a possible solution to my problem .

Answer (score 0):

E.g.,

```
${person_name}=   Set Variable    Matt
${department}=    Set Variable    R&D
# then your code continues
${rest_of_the_url} /api/${department}/${person_name}
```

[Set Variable](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Variable.) documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! As I said in the first post, using variables this way isn’t possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see this using the Set Test / Suite / Global Variable keywords here:
https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html

Use "Set Suite Variable" keyword then enter the variables $ {person_name} e
$ {department} inside *** Variables *** then you should read the value inside the test.